# Android activity restarts wrong Activity after system "kills"app

Tags: android

I have an app with several activities. I enter my app, go from activity A > B > C. Go to home screen. I click the launcher icon, it resumes activity C. All good so far. However, if I repeat this, but then open 10/15 apps, and try it again, Android restarts activity A with a backstack of C, B, A. Clicking back *should* go home, but it resumes activity C.

I've tried singleTop and standard launch modes for the main activity. No help!